# namespace autoloading with composer and PSR-0

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload, psr-0

I want Implemente the namespace autoloading with composer and PSR-0, and I don't know why it dosen't work.

there is my file structure:

```
src
   |app
       | world 
              | World.php
      
       | user
             | User.php
vendor
Test.php
composer.json
```

in **World.php**

```
<?php

namespace world;
class World {
    public function hello() {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
?>
```

in **User.php**

```
<?php
namespace user; 
class User {
    public function hello() {
        return "hello user";
    }
}
?>
```

in **composer.json**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "my": "src/app"
        }
    }
}
```

and when I test this in **Test.php** :

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class Myworld {
    public function testhello() {
        $w = new my\librairie\World();
        echo $w->hello();
        $u = new my\user\User();
        echo $u->hello();
    }
}

$m = new Myworld();
$m->testhello();
?>
```

I get this error :

> Fatal error: Class 'my\user\User' not found
>
> Fatal error: Class 'my\world\World' not found

what I miss !? Any advice would be welcome! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no namespace part "my" in your definitions.

```
namespace user; 
class User {...}
```

This class is named `\user\User`, not `\my\user\User`.

The same applies to `\world\World`.

Consequently the namespace definition in Composer is wrong. You'd need two definitions for both `user` and `world`, both in the same directory:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "user\\": "src/app",
            "world\\": "src/app"
        }
    }
}
```